# Is my algorithm for determining whether a ipv4 is public or private correct?

Tags: c++, algorithms, networking, ip-address

I have just created a function which checks whether a ipv4 is public or not. I have not heavily tested it yet since it is kind of practically impossible to do so (because I do not know where to start).

My algorithm is based on an article from [this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20190816084104/http://blog.adiglobal.us/private-and-public-ip-address-ranges).

> Public IP addresses will be issued by an Internet Service Provider and
> will have number ranges from 1 to 191 in the first octet, with the
> exception of the private address ranges that start at 10.0.0 for Class
> A private networks and 172.16.0 for the Class B private addresses.

Is this algorithm correct (implemented here in C++) ?

```
struct IpAddress {
    uint8_t oct1;
    uint8_t oct2;
    uint8_t oct3;
    uint8_t oct4;
};

bool isIpPublic(const IpAddress &ip){
    if (ip.oct1 >= 1 && ip.oct1 <= 191){            // not class C
        if (ip.oct1 != 10){                         // not class A (all of class A is private)
            if (ip.oct1 != 172 && ip.oct2 != 16){   // not class B (172.16.x.x is private)
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This question is off topic, but I will tell you that the article is quite wrong.

Comment: please help me then. please help correct my algorithm...

Comment: While it is not authoritative, nor its information always reliable, [Wikipedia is a good start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4). And it lists four ranges of private addresses, and some others you *might* want to include in that too.

Comment: @Deduplicator  I count [three on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Private_networks) and they are the same as in OP's referenced article...

Comment: The quote within the question is totally wrong.

Comment: @Christophe I counted the link-local addresses too.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, true ! Then we have 5 with the loopback :-) And of course the question is if the limited broadcast 255.255.255.255 and similar special purpose addresses shall count as public, private, or neither public nor private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Basic address analysis

There are [three IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Private_networks) ranges reserved for private addresses according to [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918).

```
Pattern           Class        Remark 
10.xxx.xxx.xxx      A 
172.YYY.xxx.xxx     B          YYY is between 16 and 31 included
192.168.xxx.xxx     C
```

Unfortunately, your function fails completely. For example:

- an address in the 194.xxx.xxx.xxx would be evaluated as private, while it is not.
- an address in the 11.xxx.xxx.xxx range would be evaluated as private, while it is not
- an address in the 172.31.xxx.xxx range would be evaluated as public while it is not.

You need to rewrite your code, not with nested ifs, but with an if/else chain.  Be aware that for class C the 16 is only a part of the truth, as some bit level manipulation would be required;  the range 16-31 is more practical here. For example:

```
bool isIpPublic(const IpAddress &ip){
    if (ip.oct1 == 10)                                   // class A private
        return false;
    else if (ip.oct1==172 && ip.oct2>=16 && ip.oct2<=31) // class B private
        return false;              
    else if (ip.oct1==192 && ip.oct2==168)               // class C private
        return false;                          
                           /* you could also combine all these conditions in a
                           single large boolean expression in a single if */
                                                
    return true;                                         // by default it's public
}
```

#### Advanced address analysis

Note that this is a simplified analysis: there are also special purpose addresses mentioned in [RFC 6890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890), which are not to be (or cannot be ) used for public addresses either.  For example:

- Loopback address: 127.xxx.xxx.xxx
- Link local addresses 169.254.xxx.xxx
- Broadcast in the current network 255.255.255.255

IANA maintains a registry of such special addresses [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml). In this note, there's a link for [downloading this registry in CSV format](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry-1.csv).  The best would then be to download this file automatically and use the field `Globally reachable` to determine if an address is public.

Comment: Administratively scoped multicast addresses are also in some sense "private", depending on how, *precisely*, the OP defines "private".

Comment: I think the loopback address is `127.0.0.0/8`, i.e. even `127.x.x.x`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think you are right. - corrected!

Comment: [rfc6598](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6598) describes the motivation for allocating `100.64.0.0/10`.